# ¿Cómo llamar a un método de otra clase con arrays como parámetros?

Tags: java, clase, método

Lo que quiero es llamar desde mi clase ***principal***, un método de mi clase funciones, el cual tiene una función con 2 arrays como parámetros, es decir:

**mi clase principal**

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main (String[] args){
                Funciones obj = new Funciones();
                obj.distancia(B1,B2);
}
```

**mi clase funciones**

```
public class Funciones {

    public int distancia(byte[] B1, byte[] B2){
    ...
    }
...
}
```

He probado a poner en mi clase principal

```
byte[] B1;
byte[] B2;
```

pero me da error en los parámetros en `obj.distancia(B1,B2)`;

Comment: Cómo has declarado B1 y B2 en la clase principal?

Comment: byte[] B1; 
byte[] B2;

Comment: Que errores te está dando? Porque parece que los parámetros que le pasas son correctos

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The local variable B1 may not have been initialized
 The local variable B2 may not have been initialized

 at Principal.main(Principal.java:59)

Comment: para ser mas exactos me falto poner:

public class Principal {

    public static void main (String[] args){
                ...
                try{
                Funciones obj = new Funciones();
                obj.distancia(B1,B2);
                ...
                }
catch...{
...}
}

Comment: y no se... digo yo... que podrías... inicializar B1 y B2 no?? si eso vamos

Comment: Probé lo de inicializar pero seguía dando un fallo y probando ya solucione el error gracias.

Comment: Asi de primeras, inicializa las variables b1 y b2 aunque te siga fallando habras quitado un error, cuando lo hagas comentas cual es tu siguiente error

Comment: Tienes que inicializarlos primero. Dales un valor null servira.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que inicializar los arreglos:

```
byte[] B1 = new byte[10];
byte[] B2 = new byte[10];
```

O bien, puedes inicializarlos a **null** (aunque no creo que sea eso lo que quieras):

```
byte[] B1 = null;
byte[] B2 = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

"public int distancia(byte[] B1, byte[] B2)" indica que es una funcion que recibe 2 parametros de tipo array(byte[] B1, byte[] B2) y cuyo valor de retorno es un entero.
Los arrays deben estar inicializados y "obj.distancia()" deberia ser contenido en una variable tipo int, debido que es el tipo de variable que retorna de esa funcion.

Se veria algo parecido a esto:

public static void main (String[] args){
                Funciones obj = new Funciones();
                byte[] B1 = new byte[10];
                byte[] B2 = new byte[10];//como lo muestra la respuesta de arriba
                int ret=obj.distancia(B1,B2);